# Коррекция цен на товар относительно курса доллара

Tags: javascript, c#, c++, jquery

Может есть у кого идеи как мне на сайте обновлять цены относительно курса доллара который мне даёт поставщик,привязаться к банку не могу, нужна лишь идея не реализация

Comment: Цены хранишь в долларах, умножаешь на стоимость доллара которую даёт поставщик

Comment: У меня должна быть цена в гривне на сайте, а при изменении курса нужно их менять каждую отдельно ты этом проблема

Comment: В заказе храни в гривне (или цена в долларах и ссылка на курс валюты, или всё вместе), в каталоге показывай вычисляя из `цена в долларах * курс`

Answer (score 0):

Добавь в переменные окружения на сайте курс валюты, если winserver с iis хостингом то win+r, cmd, enter и set Rate="курс валюты, например гривна к доллару", хорошим тоном будет указать так [Название_Проекта]:["Например Billing"]:Rate. Затем если в каком нибудь сервис методе или менеджере (в зависимости от структуры проекта) объявляешь метод для конвертации одной валюты в другую используя значение из переменной окружения. Переменная окружения нужна что бы можно было менять значение курса без перевыкладки приложения. Затем при формировании модели можно этим методом конвертить валюту или выделить под него rest метод и при необходимости вызывать каким нибудь XmlHttpRequest'м (если разрешен cors). Тут важно понимать, что как вы организуете метод конвертирования зависит только от вас, это может быть и примитивный GetUsdFromUah(int uahValue) или же это что более гибкое и мощное, плюсы - возможность управлять курсом как на бэке так и во фронте по rest-api, к примеру актуально если вы с бэка работаете с платежным шлюзом нацеленным на работу с одной конкретной валютой, но оплату можете принимать в разных валютах. Вместо переменной окружения можно использовать и конф.файл и какой нибудь метод который будет парсить актуальный курс и т.д.

Другой вариант, использовать только фронт и какую нибудь библиотеку типа money.js, тут все еще проще. На фронте при необходимости получаете актуальный курс нужной вам валюты и делаете конвертацию.